# image button with transparency

Tags: java, android

I am totally new to Android development, please excuse my ignorance, but is it possible to make an image button that receives onClick events only when the user clicks on a non-transparent pixel of the button's image?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything specifically like what you describe, but you could set an OnTouchListener for the ImageView and use the getX() and getY() functions of the corresponding MotionEvent.

Alternatively you could slice your image and have a grid layout of some sorts. I am not sure what performance for that would be like.

Bear in mind that touch screen events are not going to be very accurate from the user.